Storing a value for each variant of enum
I am writing a little game engine with winit and wgpu crates and I need to store for each key whether or not it is currently pressed.
pub struct Game {
    ...
    pub keys_pressed: HashMap<winit::keyboard::KeyCode, bool>,
}

Coming from C/C++ I know it is not necessary to use a HashMap for such simple thing where all values are distrete and I really want to use something like simple array but I don't know how to. Also, I would like to initialize the array with false values for each key.
pub struct Game {
    ...
    pub keys_pressed: [winit::keyboard::KeyCode; bool; false],
}

I tried enum_map create, which worked great for my own enums, but KeyCode is defined outside of my crate, so Rust wouldn't let me impl Enum for KeyCode {}.

What is your question here?

Rust doesn't support arrays index by anything else than usize. However, you can cast a Keycode to a usize using keycode as usize where keycode: Keycode. You just need to know in advance the number of variants of the KeyCode enum, to create an array big enough, which, by design, you can't know (KeyCode is marked as non_exhaustive, meaning it's not considered as a breaking change to add new variants).
